# calling a promise within a promise , with $q.all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have multiple api requests which can run in parallel.

getlocations, getstates, get territories can make a request in parallel. however once i have the states list from getstates() call, i need to make an api request for each individual state and parse the state object.

Here is the code that i have so far, Is it ok to call a promise within a promise this way ?

```
  getAllLocations() {
    //make a promise call for all here .
    var promise = [];
    //first prmise
    promise.push(this.getAllLocations(Id).then(
        (locationsData) => {
            this.locations = locationsData;
        }));
    //second promise
    promise.push(this.getAllStates(Id).then(
        (resp) => {
            this.states = resp.data;
            //for each state , need to make an api call and add to the state info
            angular.forEach(this.states, function(state){
                var nodeId = state.Id;
                this.getStateSummary(nodeId).then((resp) => {
                    state.healthStatus = resp.data.operationalStatus;
                });
            },this)
        }));
    //third promise
    promise.push(this.getAllterritories(Id).then(
        (resp) => {
            this.territories = resp.data;
        }));
    //after all promises parse teh location data
    $q.all(promise).then(() => {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.locations.length; i++) {
            //do something with with location here
        }
        this.gridData = this.locations;
    });
}
```

if not , whats the best way to make teh getStatesummary() call ?

Comment: are you sure values are pushing to the array this way

Comment: no , it's not . would like to know how exactly should i do this

Comment: `this.$q.all` ?

Comment: prior to getStatesummary , teh promise call was working correctly

Comment: does `getAllStates(Id)` resolve to a regular Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simplify each of the 3 promises (especially 1 and 3), so that this.locations, this.states and this.territories are all updated in the $q.all .then - you don't have to, but I think it makes the code a little more readable

Next, assign all 3 promises to a variable (p1, p2, p3 in the code below)

The next issue is waiting on all the states API calls to complete - another $q.all required there

All up, with a little extra ES6 goodness, you get

```
getAllLocations() {
    //first prmise
    const p1 = this.getAllLocations(Id);
    //second promise
    const p2 = this.getAllStates(Id).then(resp => 
        //for each state , need to make an api call and add to the state info
        $q.all(resp.map(state => this.getStateSummary(state.Id).then(resp => state.healthStatus = resp.data.operationalStatus)))
        .then(() => resp) // so we return data for this.states
    );
    //third promise
    const p3 = this.getAllterritories(Id).then(resp => resp.data);
    //after all promises parse teh location data
    $q.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(([locations, states, territories]) => {
        this.locations = locations;
        this.states = states;
        this.territories = territories;
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            //do something with with location here
        }
        this.gridData = this.locations;
    });
}
```

If the getAllStates promise returns a Object instead of my assumption that it's an array - then replace the inner `$q.all` with

```
        $q.all(Object.entries(resp).map(([key, state]) => this.getStateSummary(state.Id).then(resp => state.healthStatus = resp.data.operationalStatus)))
```

Actually, the above code would work for Array or Object equally :p

Comment: thanks @Jaromanda X , however for p2, i don't see a return statement for this.states

Comment: arrow function - `param => value` === `param => { return value; }` (there was a stray `;` in the code, fixed now)

Comment: got it , @Jaromanda X  i tried the solution you provided. however after the getStateSummary() call, the state.healthStatus is not updated.

Comment: yeah, I may have been too clever ... hang on

Comment: Hmmm, logic is sound. in `getAllStates(Id).then((resp) => ...` what is `resp`? - is it an Array?

Comment: Updated the answer in case resp is an Object rather than my assumption that it is an Array

Comment: Having said all that, I know in the past I've seen interesting "issues" with "nested" `$q` promises not behaving as Promise/A+ compliant Promises should - is there any reason to use `$q` over native (or polyfilled in the case of IE) **`Promise`** 's?

Comment: Appreciate your answer ,  @Jaromanda X but this still does not update this.states with heathStatus. I see that the .then part where resp => state.healthStatus = resp.data.operationalStatus happens after $q.all([p1, p2, p3]).then which is where the health status needs to be available.                If using $q is not required , i can used Promises, how would that play in ? in case of making it better?

Comment: change `$q.all` to `Promise.all`

Comment: I just dummied up (like really hacky) a test using $q - and it seems to work fine - https://jsfiddle.net/Lk3u7e8p/

Answer (score 0):

you can use **promise chain** to send catch promises one after the another

```
 getAllLocations() {
     //make a promise call for all here .
     var promise = [];
     //first prmise
     this.getAllLocations(Id)
         .then(
             (locationsData) => {
                 this.locations = locationsData;
                 promise.push(this.locations);

                 return this.getAllStates(Id)
             }).then(
             (resp) => {
                 this.states = resp;
                 //for each state , need to make an api call and add to the state info
                 angular.forEach(this.states, function(state) {
                     var nodeId = state.Id;
                     return this.getStateSummary(nodeId);
                 }, this)
                 return this.getAllterritories(Id);
             }).then((resp) => {
             state.healthStatus = resp.data.operationalStatus;
             promise.push(state.healthStatus);
         }).then(
             (resp) => {
                 this.territories = resp.data;
                 promise.push(this.territories);
                 this.callAll(promise)
             })
 }


 callAll(promise) {
     //after all promises parse teh location data
     this.$q.all(promise).then(() => {
         for (var i = 0; i < this.locations.length; i++) {
             //do something with with location here
         }
         this.gridData = this.locations;
     });
 }
```

Comment: `use promise chain` ... vs the question which says `can make a request in parallel`

Comment: thanks, but would like to make the calls in parallel for getlocations, getstates and getterritories as they dont have any data that is dependent . only statesummary call is dependent on getstates